# Why do the numerical values get stored in scientific notation in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, format

I have tried to change the format to `int` but I will lose the accuracy. I do not want to display the value in scientific notation.

Any clue why does it save the values in scientific notation?

Comment: IEEE floating point numbers are the internal representation; that's how they work.  Display is another matter entirely.

Comment: Numbers aren't "stored" in scientific notation (except maybe if you're saving them as text) they are only displayed this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the MATLAB function `format` to change how numbers are displayed by default  `format short`, `format long`, etc.

If you want to display numbers with more control over the exact format, for example to control how many decimal points to display or to zero pad to keep field width/filename length a constant, use `sprintf`, optionally along with `disp`.  For example:

```
sprintf('%0.5f',1/eps)          % 4503599627370496.00000
sprintf('%0.5g',1/eps)          % 4.5036e+15
sprintf('%05d.txt',1);          % 00001.txt
sprintf('%05d.txt',1000);       % 01000.txt
```

`fprintf` is like `sprintf` but for writing to file (the formatting commands are the same).  You're not actually changing the number, just the display, so these functions are useful if you want a function or script to display some sort of output in a human-readable fashion, while retaining the more accurate values for calculation:

```
n = 5;
m = 50.53962983
disp(sprintf('Iteration %d: %2.2f',n, m)); % Iteration 5: 50.53
disp(m);  % 50.5396 - depends on your format setting
disp(sprintf('%0.8f',m)) % 50.53962983
```